# Oracle impdp error when importing data

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, datapump

I get this error `ORA-02289: sequence does not exist` when I try to import a schema to my database, could you give me some recommendation?

**Import Command:**

```
impdp '"sys/mmm as sysdba"' directory=BACK_IMPORT dumpfile=0502190800%U.dmp 
logfile=impdp_MBD.log SCHEMAS=MSCHEM PARALLEL=7 encryption_password=0qazw
```

**Export Command:**

```
expdp '"sys/mmm as sysdba"' encryption=all encryption_password=0qazw 
encryption_algorithm=aes256 COMPRESSION=ALL DIRECTORY=BACK_EXPORT 
COMPRESSION_ALGORITHM=BASIC LOGTIME=ALL CONTENT=ALL flashback_time=systimestamp 
DUMPFILE=$name% U.dmp LOGFILE=$name.log PARALLEL=7 SCHEMAS=MSCHEM,IOOUT,ZHIST;
```

Comment: From oracle community check this [link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9533916100346734356)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing **MSCHEM** schema. Please check in source database that one of TABLE/Procedure/Package using a sequence that exist in another schema. If so, don't worry just recreate it. you can find this sequence name in import log also.